# Возврат некорректного значения

Tags: c#, .net

Создал массив состояний заказа, создал enum-ы под состояния заказа, ввожу в консоль ID заказа возвращается его статус.
При вводе в консоль ID заказа, вместо значения из массива возвращается сам Enum, а default не срабатывает, возвращая введенный ID

```
class Program
{

    static string GetAnswer(Status answer)
    {
        string[] item = new string[] { "в обработке", "оплачено", "в пути", "доставлен", "неизвестый заказ" };
        string answerType;
        switch(answer)
        {
            case Status.Processing:
                answerType = item[0];
                break;
            case Status.Paid:
                answerType = item[1];
                break;
            case Status.InWay:
                answerType = item[2];
                break;
            case Status.Delivered:
                answerType = item[3];
                break;
            default:
                answerType = item[4];
                break;
        }
        return answerType;
    }



    enum Status
    {
        Processing = 1,
        Paid,
        InWay,
        Delivered
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать!");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер заказа");

        var itemNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        var answer = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), itemNumber);

        Console.WriteLine(answer);




        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

Comment: Пардон, а для чего нужен массив, когда в конечном итоге идет попытка надругательства на перечислением? Цель всего этого какая?

Comment: Я сам задавался этим вопросом, но это задание сверху.

Comment: Метод `GetAnswer` не вызывается в `Main`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это ответ лучший, но он показывает что я сам дурак и не вызывал собственный метод! Спасибо!